# i7 7700K high temperatures on ASUS Z270 motherboard

Tags: cpu, motherboard, temperature, overheating

I have upgraded my device and I have gone from an **MSI H110M Pro-D** motherboard to an **ASUS STRIX Z270H GAMING K1**.

The problem I have is that with this new motherboard my **i7 7700K** gets much hotter when I play than with the previous motherboard.

Monitoring temperatures with **MSI Afterburer** it used to be around **65º** with the old mobo, with the new one the temperatures were around **70-85** degrees, I have even reached a peak of **91º**.

I have lowered the voltage as much as I could using the **Intel Extreme Tuning Utility**. Now I am testing it with an **offset at -0.065V** (with less blue screen shows up). With this config I have managed to lower it to about **60º - 70º** although many times it goes up to **75º** even **80º**.

The hardest thing for me to understand (I know practically nothing about overclocking and related things) is that when I do the stress tests (forcing 100% load on the CPU) with the **Intel Extreme Tuning Utility**, the temperatures are around **64º - 74º** with **minimum peaks of 63º and maximum of 76º**, but when I play games I have peaks of **84º** and on several occasions I exceed **74º** while the CPU use never reaches **100%** in fact, normally (in the game in which I have been doing the tests) it has a use of **25% - 40%** reaching a maximum of **80% - 90%** on rare occasions.

I do not understand much about voltages but here I leave an image with the default voltage and another with the voltage at -0.065V:

**Normal:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHsPx.jpg

**-0.065V offset:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ga63L.jpg

**BIOS information** (I haven't changed any settings, nor do I really know what to touch): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipNYH.jpg

**MSI Afterburning screenshots:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVT8F.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWPqA.jpg

Comment: If the cooling system is not functioning properly (and I’m saying it isn’t) then why are you trying to compensate by changing voltages and destabilizing your system? Take the computer back apart and fix the cooling.

Comment: The cooling system is working the same as before. I only changed the fan settings to not operate at low temperatures (the two case fans I have installed). They start operating at 55º.

Comment: You changed motherboards. That means you removed the cpu and heatsink. It is not working the “same as before.” According to you it is running hotter. That is not a motherboard issue. That is an issue with your cooling system.

Comment: With the old motherboard I had the CPU fan and one chassis fan. With this one I could plug the second chassis fan, so now I have 2 chassis fans instead of one. I also bought NOCUA thermal paste (I even put it twice since I thought it was the thermal paste issue at first. But I don't know what issue could be happening with the cooling system since when it reaches high temperatures the fans spin at maximum speed as they should.

Comment: I’m sorry I can’t offer any more help beyond general suggestions. Without seeing your system I can’t tell you why it runs warmer. The cpu and heatsink need to be bonded together by a very thin layer of thermal paste. The two surfaces need to seat perfectly. Your fans need to aid in moving cool air in and hot air out, so that they are not fighting with each other and causing hot spots. Not much else I can say. Do some research and further troubleshooting. The board itself may be generating more heat or in different areas and you need to compensate for that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check the fans. Do you know any way to measure the air flow? I'm really lost in cooling terms.